# Values lossing in fscanf

Tags: c, string, char, scanf

The IDE I used is Clion.
I wanna read the Line-separated data stored in .txt file.
Each line contains firstname, surname, gender, ID and age, which are str, str, str, int and int.

StudentList.txt

```
Olivia SWANSON F 29001 20
Emma ONEILL F 7900 19
```

I try to use `fscanf` to read the data.

```
FILE *fp;
char fname[20];
char sname[20];
char gender[1];
int ID;
int age;
fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Catlover\\Desktop\\DSA\\Program2\\StudentList.txt", "r");
while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %d %d", fname, sname, gender, &ID, &age)!= EOF)
{
    printf("%s,%s,%s,%d,%d\n", fname, sname, gender, ID, age);
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

But the result it return looks like a little bit weird becasue it doesn't output the second value.

Result is

```
Olivia,,F,29001,20
Emma,,F,7900,19
```

Something shocks me is that the same code runned in PellesC lead to the correct result.

I used to learn C++ so there may exists some important rules in C but I didn't notice. Can anyone show that for me?

Comment: By the way, I try to output the 'sname' individually and set a breakpoint. There is no value transmit into the 'sname'.

Comment: `gender` is too small to hold a character plus a null terminator. C strings are null-terminated strings, which requires one additional char for the terminator. Your call to `fscanf` writes to the array beyond its end, which causes undefined behaviors, which is why it happens to work in one environment but not another.

Comment: Also, "The complier I used is Clion" - No, CLion is an IDE, not a compiler toolchain.

Comment: Does this occur if you declare `gender` after `age`?

Comment: It just like what kotatsuyaki said, the gender array is too small to hold the value and terminator, when I extend the size of gender from 1 to 2, the problem stop occuring. Really helpful, Thanks!

Comment: @catlover, Note that a person's first and/or last name may have spaces in it rendering `"%s"` unsuitable for reading name part.    20 is insufficient for some names.  [Extreme example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Blaine_Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff_Sr.).

Comment: @catlover `"%s"` reads and saves non-white-spaces including `','`.  You need another approach to use `','` as a separator.  Yet once that is fixed, you may run into another name issue.  Rather than address these issues one by one, Take time to think out many of the [possible name issues.](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20160325-the-names-that-break-computer-systems)  If after trying to solve many issues, post another question then if still stuck.  For [fun](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`"%s"` without *width***

Never use `"%s"` in a `*scanf()` without a width to indicate the max number of non-white-space characters to read and save.  Recall that after reading, a *null character* is appended.  Example: if the buffer size is 100, code can only read up to 99.
`char gender[1];` is too small for `"F"`.

**Wrong check**

`fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %d %d", ...)` can return other values than `5` or  `EOF`.  As only `5` is acceptable, test against that.

**Test open success**

If `fopen()` fails, `fscanf()`, `fclose()` are bad

**Other issues exist too***

But lets use start with fixing the above.

---

```
char fname[20 + 1];
char sname[20 + 1];
char gender[1 + 1];
int ID;
int age;
FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Catlover\\Desktop\\DSA\\Program2\\StudentList.txt", "r");
if (fp) {
  while(fscanf(fp, "%20s %20s %1s %d %d", fname, sname, gender, &ID, &age) == 5) {
    printf("%s,%s,%s,%d,%d\n", fname, sname, gender, ID, age);
  }
  fclose(fp);
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have space to accommodate `null` byte also.

```
char gender[1];
```

to

```
char gender[2];
```